# Problems combining two strings using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having issues combining two strings in bash on Linux.
My end goal is simply to add a / to an existing path I have stored as a variable. Essentially I just want the path to lead into the folder instead of just to the folder itself.

The file path is fetched from an environment variable and so far everything I have tried to combine the file path with any form of string has simply failed.

At first, I assumed that it was an error caused by the / being seen as some special character so I've been testing with just normal strings but I haven't been able to make that work either.

Here's my test code:

```
filename=$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS

stringtest=boo

mytest="$filename$stringtest"

zenity --info --text=$mytest
```

I have tried also tried:

```
filename+="boo"
filename+="$stringtest"
filename="${filename} test"
filename="${filename} ${stringtest}"
mytest=$filename$stringtest
filename=$(printf "%s boop" "$filename")
```

No matter what I seem to do I only get the file path as an output. The only time I have had any success was when adding the file path to another string instead of adding a string to the file path.

Thanks for the read

EDIT:
As suggested by @thatotherguy below, I was missing "" around my variable mytest in my zenity command. Adding those solved it. Thanks

Comment: Where are you adding a / in any of that string concatenation?

Comment: I tried all your lines of code and they all work.  The only difference is I had `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of my test script.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is that `$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` has a trailing space. Since you don't quote `"$mytest"` in your zenity command, you will only ever show the first word of it. Please run the script with `bash -x` to get a debug log, and edit your post to include it.

Comment: @Shawn As I mentioned, I tried with a / at first but since it did not work I have been testing the other methods with normal strings, my thought being that / might be a special character that could cause problems in my problem-solving.

Comment: @thatotherguy Welp... I knew it had to be something small I had missed. Adding the "" around mytest in the zenity command as you suggested solved it. Thanks! Will edit post to include it as the answer.

Comment: @underscore [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically warns about this and other common issues. You can install it in your editor and have it point out these things while you're writing the script.